# How to disable azure cosmos db continious backup

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, backup

I enabled the Azure cosmos DB continuous backup for one of my Cosmos DBs.

 
How can I disable it?
It just says you have successfully enrolled in continuous backup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have seen this message in the portal when you created the account/also mentioned in the doc

**"You will not be able to switch between the backup policies after the account has been created"**

since you need to select either **"Periodic"** or **"Continuous"** at the creation of Cosmos Account, it becomes mandatory.

Update:

You will not see the above in portal anymore, you can Switch from "Periodic" to "Continous" on an existing account and that cannot be reverted. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/migrate-continuous-backup#portal).

[image]

Comment: The emphasized quote is not entirely correct. It seems it is possible to switch from "Periodic" to "Continuous" by just enabling it under "features" in portal.

Comment: only at the creation of accoun, there is no way to switch

Comment: Well, I just did switch from "Periodic" to "Continuous" in an existing account. Haven't verified Point-in-time restore works, but the option is there in portal.